# facebook's graph gives different shares values, rather than a share button

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook share button with a counter on my website, it shows me 776.

but when I did http://graph.facebook.com/URL_OF_WEBSITE it gave me 550...

First I thought that they didn't update their counters, but the next day graph gave me 552.

and I don't know if they count something else, on share button? and which one is the most truth.

Answer (score 1):

From: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

**What makes up the number shown on my Like button?**

The number shown is the sum of:

- The number of likes of this URL
- The number of shares of this URL (this includes copy/pasting a link back to Facebook)
- The number of likes and comments on stories on Facebook about this URL
- The number of inbox messages containing this URL as an attachment.